# Creating a correlation matrix via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, correlation

What would be the best way to create a correlation matrix via Excel VBA?  My data has 45 columns (which may eventually change) and 12000 rows (which can change as well).  I was going to just use the `correl` function on the sheet but like I said, my columns and rows may change with time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Mcorrel", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$3:$F$6"), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$10"), "K", False //"K" might be "C"=column
```

to run this you have to enable Data Analysis Toolpack (package) first.
You can use this via UI, tab Data Analysis->correlation matrix

here:

```
"$C$3:$F$6" - input (square matrix)
$C$10 - output cell
"K" (or "C") - group by columns
false - labels=no
```

Comment: I get `P:\ATPVBAEN.XLAM cannot be found. Try a different path`.  The analysis toolpak is located in our C Drive and I can get the path where it is located but not sure how to edit the above code to do that.

Comment: @Kristina you have to enable this via ribbon->Excel's Options->Addins->manage

Comment: Is there a way for the correlation matrix to be instantly updated if the range data changes?

Comment: yes, but then you have to use events. You can write code in the Worksheet_Change event procedure to take some action depending on which cell was changed or based upon the newly changed value. also you can upvote my post, thanks  : p  [about Excel events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

Comment: Thanks again! Since I'm not too familiar with events, I opted for the user to click a button. I do have one last question.  How can I change any error values in my matrix to 0?

Comment: @Kristina what do you mean by changing error values? do you mean substitute some incorrect values in your input?

Comment: @Kristina and remeber: the simplest way in Excel to know how to code macro is to RECORD MACRO, you can do it via Developer tab on ribbon, the macro will be recorded in module and you can investigate it in Excel "IDE" alt+F11

Answer (score 4):

I have searched the web for VBA Correlation Matrix Code and havent found anything of substance. Did some coding myself, it aint beautiful, however it does the job.
This code will create a matrix to the right of the last data series.

```
Sub CorrelationMatrix()

Dim y As Range
Dim z As Range

funds = Application.Workbooks("VBAcorrelation").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,       Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
rader = 0
For x = 1 To funds
        nyrad = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
        If nyrad > rader Then
        rader = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next x



p = 1
u = 2

For h = 1 To funds
For u = 1 To funds

        Set y = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, h), Cells(rader, h))
        Set z = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, u), Cells(rader, u))

  Correl = WorksheetFunction.Correl(y, z)

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(h + 1, funds + u + 3).Select
 ActiveCell = Correl

 Next u
 Next h

MsgBox "Done with Matrix"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This pair of functions give you the result in a matrix (select the range where it should appear, introduce the formula, then press F2 and then Ctrl+shift+enter to see the values). Copy both and paste on the VBA editor.

```
'function to create a correlation matrix given the data
Function CorrMatriz(Mat_data As Variant)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, corr As Variant, M1 As Variant, M2 As Variant
ReDim corr(1 To Mat_data.Columns.Count, 1 To Mat_data.Columns.Count)

ReDim M1(1 To Mat_data.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
ReDim M2(1 To Mat_data.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To Mat_data.Columns.Count
    M1 = ExtraeMatriz(Mat_data, i)
    For j = 1 To Mat_data.Columns.Count
        M2 = ExtraeMatriz(Mat_data, j)
        corr(i, j) = Application.Correl(M1, M2)
    Next j
Next i
CorrMatriz = corr
End Function`

' function to extract one column
enter code here
Function ExtraeMatriz(Matriz As Variant, columna As Integer)
Dim i As Integer, data_final As Variant
ReDim data_final(1 To Matriz.Rows.Count, 1)
For i = 1 To Matriz.Rows.Count
    data_final(i, 1) = Matriz(i, columna)
Next i
ExtraeMatriz = data_final
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine:

```
Option base 1  
      Function MCorrelation(rango As Range) As Variant
        Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, s As Integer, t As Integer, c() As Variant
        ReDim c(rango.Columns.Count, rango.Columns.Count)
        For i = 1 To rango.Columns.Count Step 1
         For j = 1 To i Step 1
        c(i, j) = Application.Correl(Application.Index(rango, , i), Application.Index(rango, , j))
         Next j
        Next i
         MCorrelation = c
        End Function
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue